# How does 'this' keyword work in a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

why can the keyword 'this' access tasks which are not in the same object ?

```
 anyobject = {
  template: '#task-list',
  props: {
    tasks: {default: []}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newTask: ''
    };
  },
  computed: {
    incomplete() {
      return this.tasks.length; // I DONT UNDERSTAND HOW THIS WORKS HERE 
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

We know that every Vue application starts by creating a new Vue instance and unless specified, all declared objects encompass the same instance.

Within it, it adds all the properties from the data object to Vue’s reactivity system as suggested in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html). When these property values change, the view “reacts”, updating to match the new values.

In this case, so does the compute property. Here the declared computed property we have, is `incomplete()`. The function provided will be used as the getter function for the property `vueinstance.incomplete`

`this` has access to the external object properties because Vue has [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that makes `this.$data.property` accesible as `this.property`

This, sort of, is one of those things Vue does that makes life easy, once you get used to it.